# How does d3.js allow us to use second parameter of function as index of dataset?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Let's say I have svg with circles in there.

```
let svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width", 600).attr("height", 100)
let dataset = [5, 10, 20]
let circles = svg.selectAll("circle").data(dataset).enter().append("circle")
```

and I want to make circle's location dynamic by the index of the dataset and radius with dataset's values

```
circles.attr("cx", (d,i)=>(i*50)+25)
       .attr("cy", 50)
       .attr("r", (d)=>d)
```

I technically could pass in `i` for the "r"'s function. But I do not have to. That makes this optional parameter. I get that.

**But I want to learn how this is possible in javascript language.** So I digged deeper by looking at the [implementation of d3.js](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/src/selection/attr.js) trying to understand how they allow such an optional paremter. But I am struggling to understand what is passing the dataset's current item as well as index of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the end of the day your question asks about a very known Javascript feature: in Javascript you can pass less arguments than parameters, or more arguments than parameters. In the former the parameters without arguments are `undefined`, in the latter the extra arguments are simply ignored.

If you look at the source code you shared you'll see that `selection.attr()` internally uses [`selection.each`](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/src/selection/each.js), which is just this:

```
export default function(callback) {

  for (var groups = this._groups, j = 0, m = groups.length; j < m; ++j) {
    for (var group = groups[j], i = 0, n = group.length, node; i < n; ++i) {
      if (node = group[i]) callback.call(node, node.__data__, i, group);
    }
  }

  return this;
}
```

The most important part is this one:

```
callback.call(node, node.__data__, i, group);
```

As you can see, the callback gets passed (via [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)) `node` as `this`, and then 3 arguments:

- `node.__data__`: this is the datum
- `i`: this is the index
- `group`: this is the current group.

Therefore, even if your function inside the `attr` method doesn't have the second parameter, it still gets passed the second (and third) argument, regardless.

Here is an example passing more arguments than parameters:

```js
function callback(arg1) {
  console.log(arg1);
}

callback.call(null, "foo", "bar", "baz");
```

And here is one passing less arguments than parameters:

```js
function callback(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5) {
  console.log(arg1)
  console.log(arg2)
  console.log(arg3)
  console.log(arg4)
  console.log(arg5)
}

callback.call(null, "foo", "bar", "baz");
```

Comment: Thank you very much for detailed and clear description. I was not understanding the fact that .each was yet another method implemented by d3. I must have confused myself with default javascript's forEach.